# NPM instagram-web-api checkpoint required

Tags: npm, instagram, instagram-api

I have configured the NPM instagram-web-api package. I have instantiated the Instagram object and passed the correct credentials:

```
const Instagram = require('instagram-web-api');
const { igUsername, igPassword } = process.env
const ig = new Instagram({ username: igUsername, password: igPassword });

(async () => {

  try {
    await ig.login()
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.error && err.error.message === 'checkpoint_required') {
      console.log(err.error);
      const challengeUrl = err.error.checkpoint_url
      await ig.updateChallenge({ challengeUrl, securityCode: 670381 })
    }
  }

  const profile = await ig.getProfile()
})()
```

I am getting a 'checkpoint_required' error message and each time I start the server a Instagram verification code is sent to my email. I don't know where to enter that code or how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue. I thing we need to call an extra api for the OTP validation in order to login.
Check this out - **https://github.com/ohld/igbot/issues/630** for the solution or reference.